# Search sensitivity in dropdown (ng-select, angular)

Tags: angular, select, angular-ngselect

I'm using [ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) with a list of cities, like below:

```
cities = [
        {id: 1, name: 'MA, Boston'},
        {id: 2, name: 'FL, Miami'},
        {id: 3, name: 'NY, New York', disabled: true},
        {id: 4, name: 'CA, Los Angeles'},
        {id: 5, name: 'TX, Dallas'}
    ];
```

In the select field, if I type "MA, B" then the field filters to "MA, Boston", which is right.

But, if I type "MA Boston", the field shows no results (many users may miss commas).

Is there a way to make the search function ignore commas, or is less sensitive to them?

Here is a stackblitz with the example above:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-mbnngu

Comment: You will need to write your own custom search function and pass it to ng-select

Comment: Do you just want to ignore commas? Are there any other conditions?

Comment: Thanks!  Ideally ignore commas, periods, &s, dashes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick hack to do so would be to replace all commas with an empty string.

First, on your component.html, you will need to pass the input property binding for `searchFn` with your own [custom search function](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#inputs).

```
<ng-select 
  [items]="cities"
  [searchFn]="customSearchFn"
  bindLabel="name"
  placeholder="Select city"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedCity">
</ng-select>
```

And then, on your component.ts, you will define `customSearchFn` with the following method. It is a quick hack, but what I did is that I replaced the commas for with an empty string for that particular object. As that for instance MA, Boston will become MA Boston.

```
customSearchFn(term: string, item) {
  item.name = item.name.replace(',','');
  term = term.toLocaleLowerCase();
  return item.name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-ypolti?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Glad to help! You can actually follow the same logic to 'ignore' commas and other signs too!

Answer (score 1):

You can have a function like:

```
  searchMe(searchTerm: string, eachObject) {
      let replacedKey = searchTerm.replace(/[,\.-\s]/g, '')
      let newRegEx = new RegExp(replacedKey, 'gi');
      let purgedName = eachObject.name.replace(/[,\.-\s]/g, '')
      if (newRegEx.test(purgedName)) {
        return true
      }
      return false
  }


    <ng-select [items]="cities"
               bindLabel="name"
               [searchFn]="searchMe"
               placeholder="Select city"
               [(ngModel)]="selectedCity">
    </ng-select>
```

See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-ghnvko?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thank you, though I tried with "MA Boston" and it turned up with no results

Comment: @user749798 Yeah, I hadn't added a ignore case flag in the regex, you can check now.